# Using ExecutorService to calculate sum() on mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, executorservice

I have a MySQL table containing a large number of rows. I have a query calculating the sum() of each individual column. I'm using limit offset to separate as portions. I need to process these portions parallelly using java ExecutorService thread pool. Finally get all sum values from each portion and add them all for each column.

let the select statements be like.

```
select sum(principal_amount) as total_principal_amount, sum(interest_amount) as total_interest_amount from X limit 1000 offset 0.

select sum(principal_amount) as total_principal_amount, sum(interest_amount) as total_interest_amount from X limit 1000 offset 1000.

select sum(principal_amount) as total_principal_amount, sum(interest_amount) as total_interest_amount from X limit 1000 offset 2000.
```

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: @ernest_k shouldn't processing be faster when each query executes parallely?

Comment: This would be processed in parallel in java, but the underlying database performing the computation would be the same. Right? Would it really speed things up?